# Bulk API library for Java

Tags: bulk-api

I searched on the internet for a bulk API library for Java, but I could not find anything relevant. Do you know any bulk API library for Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java client library for Salesforce Bulk API 2.0 by endolabs
https://github.com/endolabs/salesforce-bulkv2-java

Disclaimer:
I have no affiliation with this lib, just wanted help by point out to a repo what I starred recently.

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation or lack thereof with this library.

Comment: Once my edit approved, you will see the disclaimer. Thanks for reflecting to that.